# To Add a tooltip on hover on element with class

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, hover, quill

I want to add a tooltip on the element with a particular class('mention'). What will be the correct way to do it in javascript(VUE JS).

This is my elements

```html
<span class="mention" data-index="0" data-denotation-char="@" data-id="5e4e58c31c09280007523ee6" data-value="<a href=&quot;https://web-dev.accura.onl/#/ip/user/5e4e58c31c09280007523ee6/&quot; target=_blank>abhi matta" data-link="https://web-dev.accura.onl/#/ip/user/5e4e58c31c09280007523ee6/">&#xFEFF;<span contenteditable="false"><span class="ql-mention-denotation-char">@</span><a href="https://web-dev.accura.onl/#/ip/user/5e4e58c31c09280007523ee6/" target="_blank">abhi matta</a></span>&#xFEFF;</span>
```

Till now I have searched and picked elements based on the classes and add event-listener to the elements but I'm not sure this is the correct way.

```js
let mentions = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('mention'))
console.log('mentions--->>', mentions)
if (!isEmpty(mentions)) {
    mentions.map(mention => {
        if (mention !== null) mention.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
            this.mouseOver(e)
        })
    })
}
```

[image: Example is github]

Comment: Do you have the ability to use [element-ui](https://element.eleme.cn/#/en-US/component/tooltip) in your project?

Comment: @FullStackOfPancakes Yes I do have